# Salvar arquivos com storeAs fora da pasta Storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Tenho em uma API em Laravel para armazenamento de arquivos

```
$request->file("file$i")->storeAs('categories', $nameFile)
```

Da forma que está este armazena os dados corretamente no endereço

```
/var/www/html/apiapp/storage/app/public/categories
```

Porém eu gostaria de salvar estes arquivos na pasta

```
/var/archives
```

Pois estes arquivos serão acessados por outra aplicação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O terceiro argumento do `storeAs` diz em qual *storage disk* o arquivo deve ser salvo

```
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 's3');
```

Assim, crie um novo *disk* em `config/filesystem.php` e aponte ele para `/var/archives`

```
'disks' => [

    // ...

    'archive' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/var/archives',
    ],

    // ...
```

No código:

```
$request->file("file$i")->storeAs('categories', $nameFile, 'archive')
```

Garanta que o usuário que roda o *webserver* tenha permissão para salvar nessa pasta em disco também.

Outra alternativa é compartilhar um *storage* externo, como o S3 da AWS por exemplo. A configuração para isso segue a mesma ideia.

Comment: Vlw mesmo cara, funcionou perfeitamente